# Regex to replace complete string containing a given substring

Tags: python

I have the following string,

````
str = '''
```
echo hello
```
THis works just fine . I love it 
![](/media/k-products/bf57d173-c1d7-44c4-b1fe-400c5f7e4e8c/35b17c4b-7f41-4552-8f9b-e883ccdc2c00.png)


| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Text     | Text      | ![](/media/k-products/bf57d173-c1d7-44c4-b1fe-400c5f7e4e8c/35b17c4b-7f41-4552-8f9b-e883ccdc2c00.png)    |
ss

Hello world!

living on love
'''
````

Given the following substring: `35b17c4b-7f41-4552-8f9b-e883ccdc2c00`
I would like to replace all parent strings containing the substring `35b17c4b-7f41-4552-8f9b-e883ccdc2c00`.

This implies the results should end up being something of this form:

````
str = '''
```
echo hello
```
THis works just fine . I love it 


| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Text     | Text      |    |
ss

Hello world!

living on love
'''
````

So the substring removal or replacement should remove the complete line of string `![](/media/k-products/bf57d173-c1d7-44c4-b1fe-400c5f7e4e8c/35b17c4b-7f41-4552-8f9b-e883ccdc2c00.png)` containing the substring `35b17c4b-7f41-4552-8f9b-e883ccdc2c00`

```
print(re.sub(r'\b(35b17c4b-7f41-4552-8f9b-e883ccdc2c00\w*)', ' ', str))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your regex is that you're not testing for things coming before or after the value you want:

```
re.sub(r'.*35b17c4b\-7f41\-4552\-8f9b\-e883ccdc2c00.*', ' ', str)
```

In regular expressions, `.` means any single character and `*` means "any of". So, this code takes any string containing `35b17c4b-7f41-4552-8f9b-e883ccdc2c00` and replaces it with `' '`. You don't have to worry about the newlines as newlines are not included in `.`.

However, this doesn't take into account your second usecase, which does not remove the entire string, but just the values between `|` characters. So, we need to modify this regex to handle this case:

```
re.sub(r'[^|\s]*35b17c4b\-7f41\-4552\-8f9b\-e883ccdc2c00[^|\s]*', ' ', str)
```

This regular expression modifies the previous one by replacing `.*` with `[^|\s]*`. Instead of just search for any character, this string searches for any character which is not a `|` or whitespace. We have to include the `\s` because `^|` includes whitespace and newlines, which you want excluded for your usecase.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The explanation was very useful too.